# Swift 3 ORSSerialPort read from arduino

Tags: swift, macos, swift3, arduino, orsserialport

So I'm trying to read some arduino output with the ORSSerialPort lib. 
If I use the example code, of the lib, named ORSSerialPortDemo, everything works.
Now the only thing I mis in the demo is how they used the SerialPortDemoController.swift in there viewController.

I created a standard project, that has the ViewController.swift.
The bridge header an imports are done, all references compile.
But rather then using a GUI to select the usb-port and Baud Rate, I like to set them in the code.

something like this:

```
var serial: SerialPortDemoController?
serial = SerialPortDemoController()
serial.path = "dev/cu.usbserial-A6006hPS"
serial.baudRate = 9600
serial.open()
```

Then al I need is to read from the port. That should already work, with the function: func serialPort(_ serialPort: ORSSerialPort, didReceive data: Data)?
So in this functio I could do something like this:

```
if let string = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) 
{
    print(string)
}
```

I have looked around, but nothing seems to work. If somebody could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: I would bet that the path must start with a slash: `serial.path = "/dev/cu.usbserial-A6006hPS"`

Comment: That could be, but my question is more on how to use the [ORSSerialPort](https://github.com/armadsen/ORSSerialPort) lib.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have correct serial port setup ie. RTS, DTR, CTS, DSR, and DCD pins?

From: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Begin
The default is 8 data bits, no parity, one stop bit.

Yes. the port starts with "/" ie. "/dev/cu.usbserial-A6006hPS"

From doc's
http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/ORSSerialPort/1.5.1/

Using ORSSerialPortManager is simple. To get the shared serial port manager:

Cocoa code:

```
ORSSerialPortManager *portManager = [ORSSerialPortManager sharedSerialPortManager];
```

To get a list of available ports:

```
NSArray *availablePorts = portManager.availablePorts;
```